# Add UIViewController to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I read a lot of Stackoverflow but I could not figure out how to do it.

I wand to add a `UIViewController` to a `UICollectionViewCell` with four different cell, the View of one of the cells is quite complex and the data changes constantly, therefor I want to add a controller to this view.

I could not figure out how to add `UIViewController` to the Cell as there is no `addChildViewController`.

My ViewController:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

My CollectionViewCell:

```
class CollectionViewCell1: UICollectionViewCell {


    lazy var viewController: ViewController1 = {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
        return vc
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super .init(frame: frame)
        print("Initiatetd")
        setUpViews()


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been impemented")
    }

    func setUpViews() {
        addSubview(viewController.view)
        let views: [String: Any] = ["viewController": viewController]
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[viewController]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[viewController]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[App. ViewController1
>   nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fb08df28ea0'

Comment: What line is the error happening on? Add an exception breakpoint to find the line of code causing the crash.

Comment: Thanks for answering when I want to add it as a subview

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a view controller to a cell like that. For doing what you want you need to use a container view. The documentation says that:

> Container View defines a region within a view controller's view subgraph that can include a child view controller.

Just add a container view to your cell (from Storyboard).

To connect a container view to your View Controller (where you have cells) you need to create an embed segue. To send data to the View Controller in `prepare(forSegue:)` you check the destination and do what you need.

Comment: I could not really figure it out, I normally do everything programmatically. But I tried to do it in storyboard but Xcode tells me I can not place a Container View in a reusable cells.
Basically I have to create a container view in the cell and create a segue in my parentcontroller and load the vc controller there and send it through the segue to the content cell?

Comment: @PaFi, Honestly speaking I haven't tried to create a container view programatically, but when you do it in interface builder, Xcode creates a segue (with a separate window, representing your view controller in a container view). Of course, its type is UIViewController but you can create a subclass or change its type like with any normal View Controller. And for sending data to it, in `prepare(forSegue:)` method you just check the destination (no need for segue id).

Also, does your collection view consist of only four cells?

Comment: Yes it only has four cells, but i now got it to work. I did it like this: http://khanlou.com/2015/04/view-controllers-in-cells/

Comment: I am creating an array of uiviewcontrollers and push the view of the viewcontroller through the uicollectionviewdatasource